# The URL <filename> is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, asp.net

I am using `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` to work with SharePoint 2013 files in asp.net MVC project. I am able to load file then execute the query but after loading, i have to checkout file. on checkout I am getting following error:

The URL is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.

I created this file via asp.net MVC project only. its fine while creating a file on Sharepoint via code. I also checked out that file from SharePoint directly. its working fine there.

Note:- File which needs to be checkout is under subsite.

any help would be highly appreciable.

following is my sample code:

```
 //siteUrl = xxx.com
 //subsite = acct
 //relUrl =  /acct/doclib/test.txt
using (ClientContext ctx = getContext(siteUrl))
    {
        var site = ctx.Web;
        var file = site.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relUrl);
        try
        {
            ctx.Load(file)
            ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 
            if (file.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None)
            {
                file.CheckOut();
                ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // this line is causing error
                return true;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Loading the file works with a non-existing file as well.

Try checking if the file exists with `file.Exists` before performing any other action.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.exists.aspx

Comment: i am accessing sharepoint online and file is there. i am able to checkout there but not through code.

Comment: i used file.Exists method and i am getting true. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the subsite before accessing the file:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext("https://sitecollectionurl.com/acct"))
{
  var file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/acct/doclib/test.txt");
  ctx.Load(file);
  ctx.ExecuteQuery();  
}
```